# Image Naming Convention Confusion and UIBarButtonItem

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uibarbuttonitem

I hope this is an easy fix, I just can't seem to wrap my head around one concept.

Of course with the introduction of their retina display, the api has adapted by asking developers to alter the image names for different sizes.

Now I am simply trying to create a `UIBarButtonItem` using the method `initWithImage:style:target:action:`

I have created an image named `barButtonImage.png` with these dimensions: W:20px H:19px. I have also created an image named `barButtonImage@2X.png` with these dimensions: W:40px H:38px.

I was under the assumption that the API would adapt and scale the image appropriately but when I build and run on my retina device, I am given a `UIBarButtonItem` that has appropriately scaled the height of the image down to 19px but has kept the 40px width of the image intact so I have a horizontally stretched image fitting inside a wide `UIBarButtonItem`.

Any suggestions toward what I can do to fix this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The image needs to be named with @2x, not @2X. iOS filenames on real devices are case sensitive.

Comment: That did it, thanks. Ill accept this answer just as soon as SO allows me